# Arch does not see sysvinit package

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, sysvinit, makepkg

I want to use arch with sysvinit. As stated in [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SysVinit), I downloaded and extracted `sysvinit` and `initscripts-fork`. I makepkg'd `sysvinit` with success, but afterwards `initscripts-fork` `makepkg` fails with the claim that dependency `sysvinit` is missing.

How does `makepkg` check dependency existence? How can I make it see the install (or better still, do you know other practical ways to use arch with `sysvinit`)?

Comment: By default, makepkg only builds, but not installs a package. You either have to use `makepkg -i` or install the `.pkg.tar.xz` file afterwards with `pacman -U` (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Makepkg#Usage).

Comment: I feel like an idiot right now. Please write this as an answer so i can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, makepkg only builds, but doesn't install a package. You either have to use `makepkg -i` or install the `.pkg.tar.xz` file afterwards with `pacman -U`.